# Opacity effect works from 1.0 to 0, but not 0 to 1.0

Tags: opacity, parseint, parsefloat

I wanted to increase the opacity of a div from 0 to 1.0 on the click of a button. I can decrease opacity from 1.0 to 0.0, but it does not work from 0.0 to 1.0. I also tried using `parseInt(element.style.opacity)` and `parseFloat(element.style.opacity)`, but none of those work either. 
Here's the faulty JavaScript:

```
function myF(){
var x = document.getElementById("test").style; 
x.opacity = parseFloat(x.opacity) + 0.1;
setTimeout(myF(),10);
}
```

And here's the faulty HTML:

```
<button onclick="myF()">Click to change opacity</button>
<div style="height:200px; width:200px; background-color:#656b67; opacity:0;" id="test">     </div>
```

(The following is the javascript and HTML that works for decreasing the opacity)

```
<body>
<script>
function myF(){
    var x = document.getElementById("test").style;
    x.opacity = x.opacity - 0.1;
    setTimeout(function(){myF();},10);
}
</script>
<button onclick="myF()">Click to resize</button>
<div style="height:200px; width:200px; background-color:#656b67; opacity:1.0;"     id="test"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? Did you check `visibility` and `display` css properties ?

Comment: No, I'm using JavaScript. I'll edit my code into the post.

Comment: Show us the code that decreases the opacity and runs successfully

Comment: Why the negative vote on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
setTimeout(myF(),10);
```

to

```
setTimeout(myF, 10);
```

You don't want to call the function immediately, you want to pass it to `setTimeout`.

Also, you have a never-ending loop. The function is called recursively, and there is no end condition. When invoking it immidiately, this will cause your browser to freeze.

Comment: That doesn't work either...although thanks for reminding me about the lack fo an upper bound. It still doesn't work with it though...

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/7WaJb/1/) quite well. You only might want to make the timeout a bit longer so you can notice the animation

Comment: Thanks! It works for me too now! It must have been some syntax error.

Comment: I actually found out what the error was. Apparently, my text editor was adding a random character to the code that didn't show up in the actual editing interface. So the browser had no clue what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function myF(){
  var transparent_div = document.getElementById("test");

  var opacity = parseFloat(transparent_div.style.opacity);

  if (isNaN(opacity)) opacity = 0.1;
  else opacity += 0.1;

  transparent_div.style.opacity = opacity;

  if (opacity < 1.0) setTimeout(function(){myF();},100);
}
```

If the opacity is set to "" an empty string, you will not be parsing a number, and as such Javascript will return that as a NaN object, which you can test for using isNaN(). I think that is one of your main issues; parseFloat() was the correct thing to use, you just need to check for your return value accordingly.

Comment: good point, although you can do easier by `var o = parseFloat(style.opacity) || 0;`