# CSS3 and Javascript: fade text out and then in using the same function

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a fading out and fading in effect using JavaScript and CSS3.  The goal is to have a div shrink in width when clicked and have the text contained within it simultaneously fade out.  Then when it is clicked again, the div expands back to its normal width, and the text fades back in.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="box1" onclick="slide1()">
<p class="fader">Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  #box1 {
position:relative;
left:0%;
top:0%;
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #666;
z-index:4;
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var box1
var fader

window.onload = function() {
    box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    fader = document.getElementsByClassName('fader');
    } 

function slide1(){

if(box1.style.width=='10%'){
box1.style.width='70%';
fader[0].style.opacity='1';
fader[0].style.transition='opacity 0.25s ease-in';
    }
 else {
    box1.style.width='10%';
 fader[0].style.opacity='0';
    fader[0].style.transition='opacity 0.75s ease-in';
 }
}
```

It's working for the fade-out, but for the fade-in it is immediately transitioning from 0 opacity to 1 opacity... there's no fade-in.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the transition first before the opacity?

Comment: It appears to be working in Firefox, it's just very quick. Change the duration to 1.25 to verify. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually asked a very similar question with the same issue a while back: [Opacity effect works from 1.0 to 0, but not 0 to 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699459/opacity-effect-works-from-1-0-to-0-but-not-0-to-1-0). Check the out and see if it works for you.

Otherwise, try adding a class to the fader element instead of adding a style declaration. Then, in your actual CSS, write the code for the fader element transition.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar.  I wrote a fadeOut class and a fadeIn, and then I used js to swap from one class to another depending on whether I needed to fade out or fade in.  It required a little more code but works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use even firefox or opera? I think your code won't work on safari or chrome since transition needs webkit-prefix on those browsers. You can use following code to get transition support:

```
var transform = (function () {
    var transforms = [
        'OTransform',
        'MozTransform',
        'msTransform',
        'WebkitTransform'
        ], transform = 'transform';

    while (transform) {
        if (document.body.style[transform] === undefined) {
            transform = transforms.pop();

        } else {
            return transform;

        }

    }

    return false;

}());
```

When im using CSS-transition, sometimes I change transition style and then let browser update changes before changing other styles. You can do this with timeout. On some browsers I have noticed that animation is not working unless doing that (some firefox browsers).

```
fader[0].style.transition='opacity 0.75s ease-in';
setTimeout(function () {
    box1.style.width='10%';
    fader[0].style.opacity='0';
}, 4);
```